# Add items to NavigationBar (Not using UINavigationController)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView in it, and also added a UINavigationBar.
How can I add and "edit" button and a "+" button in that bar programmatically?
(I have tried using IB, but the title is always replaced, and not other items are added)
I am not using a UINavigationController. is my UIViewController standing alone.

This is what I have tried without success:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                  target:nil
                                                  action:nil];
UINavigationItem *editItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
[editItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton animated:YES];
[navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:editItem] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your `UIViewController` has a `navigationItem` property. You can set the left and right bar button items with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...` and `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...`

**Edit:**

OK, I assume you have a reference to your `UINavigationBar`?
Then I guess you'd add a single `UINavigationItem` to it:

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A Title"];
theNavigationBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
[item release]; // or keep this as an instance variable
```

and then set that item's left and right buttons:

```
theNavigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...;
theNavigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...;
```

I haven't tried this, but I think it should work.

Comment: This is the same approach as vfn right? I didn't work. navigationItem is intended to be used when using UINavigationController, which is not my case.

Comment: Yes, it's the same approach. I edited my answer and added another possible solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, You answer is really safes a lot of time, specially you made the latest assumption which is you have a reference to the UINavigationBar not the NavigationItem, Thanks So much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(theEditMethod:)];      
[viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton animated:NO];
[leftBarButton release];

UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(theAddMethod:)];       
[viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:rightBarButton animated:NO];
[rightBarButton release];
```

Comment: I tried this inside of viewDidLoad method of the controller (and replaced viewController for self) but not working. ;(. navigationItem is intended to be used when using  UINavigationController, which is not my case.

Comment: Why don't you switch to use a navigation controller and set your view controller as root of it. It will make you life easier!

Comment: Because, first, I am not navigating. And second, I want to customize its width, something is not possible with UINavigationController. Actually I am working on an alternative way of navigating so the goal is not to use UINavigationController.

Comment: Well, remember that a UINavigationController is a subclass of a UIViewController that has a UINavigationBar added to it's UIView. If you want to create your own way to navigate, you can do it using a UINavigationController, just don't use push and pop view controllers. :). If you don't want to use the default navigation structure, I woul recommend to you to use so a UIToolbar instead of a UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need to add UINavigationItem to the UINavigationBar. Yo can do as this example:

```
NSString *backButtonTittle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"< %@",NSLocalizedString(@"backButton", nil)];
UIBarButtonItem *backCreateAccountNavBarItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:backButtonTittle style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goToBackStep)];
self.createAccountNavBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem=backCreateAccountNavBarItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use your viewController's navigationItem property.

like this:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(updateContent)];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Navigation Bar items/buttons with actions on Swift 4.2, ios 11, XCode 10**

**1)** With Storyboard go to Editor  > Embed In > **Navigation Bar**

**2)** In AppDelegate > **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "1C9B90")
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

**3)** On **viewDidLoad** for your viewcontroller, create buttons and add to Navigation Bar:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Title"
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

//QR Code button
let qrCodeScanButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
qrCodeScanButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "camera"), for: .normal)
qrCodeScanButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.searchWithQRCode), for: .touchUpInside)
let qrCodeScanButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: qrCodeScanButton)

///LogOut button
let logoutButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
logoutButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "logOut"), for: .normal)
logoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.logOut), for: .touchUpInside)
let logoutButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoutButton)

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.setRightBarButtonItems([logoutButtonItem, qrCodeScanButtonItem], animated: true)
```

**4)** Actions for buttons:

```
@objc func logout(){
     ///present your Login VC
}

@objc func qrCodeScanButton(){
     ///present your Login VC
}
```

**5)** Build and Run

*PS. Keep in mind these two differences.*

**isNavigationBarHidden**: A Boolean value that indicates whether the navigation bar is hidden.

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden
```

**navigationBar.isHidden**: The navigation bar managed by the navigation controller.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden
```