# Show Navigationbar without UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to display a Navigationbar without using a UINavigationController.
The Navigationbar should show a button on the left side and a Title in the center.
I already tried to do it like this but that don't work: [Add items to NavigationBar (Not using UINavigationController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606161/add-items-to-navigationbar-not-using-uinavigationcontroller) 
There is also a comment in the official documentation that i should not use this property if I don't use a navigation controller: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationItem 
Is this even possible and if not how could I get a similar result?

Comment: Yes, it's very possible. Are you trying to do this programmatically?

Comment: Why not use UINavigationController? You can just add one view controller to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not super intuitive but you can make this happen.

The answer you linked covers half of the solution (Creating a `UINavigationBar` and adding a `UINavigationItem` to it).

You also need to actually add the navigation bar as a subview to your view.

```
[self.view addSubview:myNavigationBar];
```