# Why does Pages get UIToolBar on top?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uitoolbar

According to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines a UIToolbar:

> “Always appears at the bottom edge of a screen or view on iPhone”

So why does the toolbar appear at the top in Apple's own Pages app? How can I do this myself?

[image]

Comment: That's a navigation bar with items/buttons.. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606161/add-items-to-navigationbar-not-using-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 1):

That's a `UINavigationBar`. But a `UIToolbar` is a `UIView` subclass; you can put it wherever you want by setting its frame or adding auto-layout constraints.